# batch convert subfolders into pdfs

Tags: batch-file, pdf

How do I go about batch converting a bunch of images, each in subfolders into pdf's using the folders names. I assume imagemagic can do this, and have it installed, but I am not sure how to do this (win7)

```
root
  |---- Sub1
  |       |-img1.png
  |       |-img2.png
  |       |-....png
  |
  |---- Sub2
          |-img1.png
          |-img2.png
          |-....png
```

run at root, and create pdf's Sub1.pdf Sub2.pdf etc.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and tell us where you are stuck...

Comment: In what programming language do you want to do it? Traditional DOS batch files, Windows Powershell, Bash shell, Python, Groovy,... ? As the commenter above wrote: show us the code you have already written so far and ask a question that is more specific.

Comment: It's comparatively easy to save text file as picture without external binaries...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
::Renaming all img to pdf extension
cd <Sub1>
REN *.png *.pdf
cd <Sub2>
Ren *.png *.pdf
::Renaming all img to Sub
cd <Sub1>
Ren *.pdf Sub*.pdf
cd <Sub2>
Ren *.pdf Sub*.pdf
```

The `<Sub1>` and `<Sub2>` have to be replaced with the path for each subfolder

Good Luck

Comment: Downvoted, because that only renames files, it doesn't convert them to PDF.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I am sorry I did not read the question clearly. But, to accomplish that you can just simply try any of the online convertors.

Comment: How are you using to batch process files with an online converter? The OP needs software that is installed on the local desktop, something like ImageMagick's `convert` will probably do the trick.